# データフレームを表示するとき、列名と各列の数値の水平位置を揃える方法

Tags: r

画像のように、出力時に列名称が各列の数値と位置が揃わない現象をなんとかしたいと考えております。

画像はオブジェクトrr　データフレームの一部です。

揃える方法をご存知の方いらっしゃいましたら
ご教授のほどお願いいたします。

環境は Windows 10 です。

[image: オブジェクトrr データフレーム]

[image]

※視認性向上のため質問情報を整理しました。

Comment: 初めに `rr` の実行結果を貼った画面と、追記でのコマンドプロンプトでは画面が違っている用に見えます。

Comment: Windows10 で R-4.1.1 を利用していますが、表示用のフォントを MS Mincho や MS Gothic に変更すると正常に表示されます。

Comment: ＞ cubickさん　コメントありがとうございます。確かにToolsのshellをクリックしただけで、初めの実行結果の直前の行為ではないので、異なってしまったようです。もう少し調べてみます。

Comment: > metropolisさん　コメントありがとうございます。フォントの変更で解決いたしました。助かりました。これでいこうかと思います。どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

皆様、どうもありがとうございました。
以下、今回の解決手段を記載させていただきます。
別の解決手段もあると思いますが、今回はこの手段で落ち着くことにします。

解決手段：表示用フォントの変更　（MSゴシックへ変更）

解決後画像：

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]